# how do rails associations get set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I always seem to have trouble with this concept. I get what associations allow you to do, I just never seem to be able to tell if the associations are set in an application.

For example, I generated a scaffold for line_items and before I ran my migration, I set the belongs_to and has_many methods in the correct models, and then ran my migration.

After running my migration, I look at my schema and I can't tell if there are any associations set. To me it does not seem like it because I don't see the schema setting any relationships.

Do the has_many and belongs_to methods actually set the association? Or are they there for developers reading the code to understand the relationship?

How would my schema look if the associations were set properly? Do I need to rollback my last migration and include the correct indexes?

```
create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price",       precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end
```

Comment: The cart_id is your association. This is saying that your Product "has many" carts. because each cart can have many products by setting their cart_id to the product id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "association" is a rails concept that is implemented by `has_many` and `belongs_to`... so those lines are not just for documentation, they create the association.

You have `product_id` and `cart_id` in the `line_items` table and I assume

```
class LineItem
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
  ...
end

class Product
  has_many :line_items
  ...
end

class Cart
  has_many :line_items
  ...
end
```

The `has_many` and `belongs_to` *do* set the associations for rails and means rails now knows that there are the associations...

```
my_line_item.cart
my_line_item.product
my_cart.line_items
my_product.line_items
```

If you didn't have the `has_many` and `belongs_to` it wouldn't work.

The columns `card_id` and `product_id` are needed for the associations to work as they're the way that records are linked and need to be present on the `belongs_to` side of the relationship.  They don't have to be called what they're called but if you don't specifically use a different foreign_key name in the `belongs_to` and `has_many` then these field names are what will be expected by rails.  And it's best to use the expected names... "Convention over configuration" is the preference.

If you did decide to call the foreign key `vegetable_id` instead of `product_id` that's fine, but then you'd define the association as

```
class LineItem
  belongs_to :product, foreign_key: :vegetable_id
```

and

```
class Product
  has_many :line_items, foreign_key: :vegetable_id
```

You can go an extra step and have...

```
class Cart
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items
  ...
end
```

This auto-magically gives you the ability to do..

```
my_cart.products
```

As rails knows how to build the SQL command to get all products for a cart via the line_items.

Because you need the foreign key in the `belongs_to` table, you would need to specify that foreign key when you create the table.

```
create_table :line_items do |t|
  t.integer :product_id
```

There is a helper_method called `references` (also aliased as `belongs_to`) which basically does the same thing... creates the `:product_id` field...

```
create_table :line_items do |t|
  t.belongs_to :product
```

or

```
create_table :line_items do |t|
  t.references :product
```

The three versions above basically do the same thing... they create the integer column `:product_id`

You can also index on the :product_id field to improve retrieval performance, so you'll occastionally see `index: true` but this isn't essential.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. Where I am getting tripped up is that when I look at the rails guide for associations, I see that the examples in there show migration files that set the relationships, so I was not sure if that was just to illustrate what was happening with has_many and belongs_to, or if you needed to include something like this in your migration file as well `create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.belongs_to :products, index: true`

Comment: I added some info to my answer to explain what `t.belongs_to` is about, hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely helps. Thanks for taking the time Steve. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

it's very simple to tell if the association is set up properly or not through your schema. basically the model has `belongs_to` should have the corresponding table that contains the `foreign_id`. For example in the schema you post, it's easy to see that the `lineItem` belongs to 'Product' and `Cart`, because it has `cart_id` and `product_id`(two foreign id).

activerecord is not a black magic, all `has_many` and `belongs_to` do is just dynamically adds a method to the model class, which translate the query to raw sql for you and map the result to ruby object. however it is your responsibility to set up the database table correctly. Because after all, activerecord use SQL to query data following rails convention.

## update

I think what you mean is the helper method in your migration file such as

```
t.belongs_to product, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

this line of code is also not a black magic, it is a helper method rails provide to make your life much easier. It is equivalent to do three simple things to create your database table.

1. create a `foreign_id` depends on your input, in the above example, it will be `product_id`. equivalent to `t.integer product_id`
2. add an index on the `foreign_id`, because usually you query out the associated data a lot by using the `foreign_id`, add an index will improve your efficiency. equivalent to `add_index "xxx", ["product_id"], name: "index_xxxs_on_product_id"`
3. at the end the `foreign_key: true` is going to set up an database constrains for your foreign_id, so that if there is still one row in your child table related to one row in your parent table, the row in your parent table will not be accidentally deleted. this is equivalent to `add_foreign_key :xxxs, :products`

so as a conclusion, using `add_foreign_key :articles, :authors` will not make anything look special in your schema, because `ActiveRecord` is just a translator to make your life easier when you deal with sql database, it can only do the thing sql database can do, not anything special. the idea of association in database is just saving a `foreign_id` in one table so that you can query the related data in another table by using the `foreign_id`.

Comment: The first part of your answer I understand, and that is set up appropriately. However, the second part of your answer is where I am getting tripped up and where this question stemmed from to begin with. Based on what you see in my schema, do the associations seem to be set? Because when I look at the rails guide for associations it seems like the relationships need to be explicitly defined in the migration file. However, when I look at tutorials for rails, they don't seem to define them in the migrations. So I am wondering if I have this configured correctly.

Comment: ya I guess you are talking about some helper method rails provide for you in migration file. such as you can do `t.belongs_to :product, foreign_key: true`. This is actually also not a magic, it is equivalent to do `t.integer "product_id"` then `add_index "xxxx", ["product_id"], name: "index_xxxx_on_product_id"` then add a foreign id constrains in database depends on which sql database you are using

Comment: anything looks fancy in rails is just a convenient tool they provide to make your life easier by following their conventions. but you can definitely do it from scratch just like what you will do without using activerecord. `ActiveRecord` is act like a translator for you to let your deal with raw sql as less as possible, but it cannot do anything that sql cannot do.

Comment: normally in database, an association is just one table is related to another table by saving the foreign id. for example, if `products` table is related to `line_items` table, you will save the related line_item's id as foreign id in products table. this is exactly how rails handle it for you. the `product:belongs_to` you run in rails generator is just a helper method does three things for you: 1. create a foreign id(in my example it will be product_id), 2. add an index on the foreign id, 3. add a constrains

Comment: thanks for going out of your way to explain all of that, it definitely made a big difference for me, so thanks. If you want to include this content as part of the answer, I think it would help if anyone else stumbles across this. I will mark this as the accepted answer